# Debian 6 and OpenSwan does not work with iPhone as client

Tags: debian, vpn, openswan, apple-ios

I have just installed OpenSwan on Debian 6.0, and  configured it according to this tutorial: http://confoundedtech.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/android-nexus-one-ipsec-psk-vpn-with.html 
There are many similar documents, and even though I change some of the parameters, I always end with the following error from xl2tpd, when I try to connect with an Iphone as the VPN client, using L2TP:

```
Apr 22 16:31:25 debian xl2tpd[19713]: network_thread: recv packet from 212.183.140.62, size = 476, tunnel = 32857, call = 10067 ref=0 refhim=0
Apr 22 16:31:25 debian xl2tpd[19713]: network_thread: unable to find call or tunnel to handle packet.  call = 10067, tunnel = 32857 Dumping.
Apr 22 16:37:52 debian xl2tpd[19713]: network_thread: recv packet from 212.183.140.62, size = 476, tunnel = 33015, call = 50076 ref=0 refhim=0
Apr 22 16:37:52 debian xl2tpd[19713]: network_thread: unable to find call or tunnel to handle packet.  call = 50076, tunnel = 33015 Dumping.
Apr 22 16:37:54 debian xl2tpd[19713]: network_thread: recv packet from 212.183.140.62, size = 476, tunnel = 33015, call = 50076 ref=0 refhim=0
Apr 22 16:37:54 debian xl2tpd[19713]: network_thread: unable to find call or tunnel to handle packet.  call = 50076, tunnel = 33015 Dumping.
Apr 22 16:37:57 debian xl2tpd[19713]: network_thread: recv packet from 212.183.140.62, size = 476, tunnel = 33015, call = 50076 ref=0 refhim=0
Apr 22 16:37:57 debian xl2tpd[19713]: network_thread: unable to find call or tunnel to handle packet.  call = 50076, tunnel = 33015 Dumping.
Apr 22 16:38:00 debian xl2tpd[19713]: network_thread: recv packet from 212.183.140.62, size = 476, tunnel = 33015, call = 50076 ref=0 refhim=0
Apr 22 16:38:00 debian xl2tpd[19713]: network_thread: unable to find call or tunnel to handle packet.  call = 50076, tunnel = 33015 Dumping.
```

This is my xl2tpd configuraition:

```
[global]
listen-addr=192.168.0.148
port=1701
debug tunnel=yes
debug avp=yes
debug packet=yes
debug network=yes
debug state=yes

[lns default]
ip range = 192.168.0.220-192.168.0.230
local ip = 192.168.0.148
require chap = yes
require authentication = yes
refuse pap = yes
ppp debug = yes
length bit = yes
pppoptfile = /etc/xl2tpd/ppp-options.xl2tpd
```

and this is my ppt-options.xl2tpd file:

```
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
noccp
auth
#crtscts
idle 1800
mtu 1410
mru 1410
nodefaultroute
debug
lock
proxyarp
connect-delay 5000
ms-dns 192.168.0.1
#name l2tpd
#lcp-echo-interval 30
#lcp-echo-failure 4
logfile /var/log/ppp.log
```

This has driven me mad, what it is I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

listen-addr should not be the same as local ip.

listen-addr - is the physical address of the host machine connecting it to the LAN/WAN
local ip - is the virtual address of the host machine for the tunnel interfacing with the virtual network

setting the two the same is probably the root of your tunnel issues,

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem. Though I got it to work under Ubuntu, but openswan allows only one connection under Debian, and after that is disconnected, no further connections are possible. That is a different question for serverfault of course :)

Comment: that will be dead peer detection if using an apple device